# Remve element from vector with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

This code does not compile.

```
            std::remove_if( m_selectedFields.begin(),
                            m_selectedFields.end(),
                            [](const FieldWin *obj, FieldWin *m_draggingField)
                            {
                                obj == m_draggingField;
                            } );
```

The `m_selectedFields` is a vector and its a member of the class, defined as `std::vector<Foo *> m_selectedFields`.
The `m_draggingField` is also a member of the class, defined as `Foo m_draggingField`.

What am I doing wrong?

The errors are:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
note: class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
```

I think lambda function should have only one argument, but then how do I pass the element that needs to be removed?

Comment: `m_draggingField` should be captured, not a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to "capture" `this` or `m_draggingField` in the lambda:

```
std::remove_if( m_selectedFields.begin(),
                m_selectedFields.end(),
                [this](const FieldWin *obj)
                {
                    obj == m_draggingField;
                } );
```

But if your predicate is really just equality, you can simplify:

```
std::remove(m_selectedFields.begin(), m_selectedFields.end(), m_draggingField);
```

Also note that `remove` and `remove_if` just reorder elements in the container, you still need to call `erase` as shown in any tutorial for these functions.

Comment: yes its just an equality.. I just want to remove the element from the vector.